# INDEX MATCH formula with multiple IF's

Tags: excel, match, lookup

I have an INDEX MATCH formula looking into one tab to collect a result:

```
=INDEX(Adjustments!C:C,MATCH('Pool data'!S17339,Adjustments!A:A,0))
```

I want to combine it with the following IF formula, so if the INDEX MATCH returns a blank cell, then it performs the following:

```
=IF(S184322=Adjustments!A17339,Adjustments!C17339,IF(D17339="",Z17339,D17339))
```

The IF statement works by itself and so does the INDEX MATCH but I just need to combine them.

Thanks

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(INDEX(Adjustments!C:C,MATCH('Pool data'!S17339,Adjustments!A:A,0)), IF(S184322=Adjustments!A17339,Adjustments!C17339,IF(D17339="",Z17339,D17339)))`

Comment: @Ralph Just curious, why post that answer as a comment rather than answer? As I understand it, comments are more to ask for clarification rather than to provide an answer.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I wrote try because I am not sure if the solution is that simple. If that's really the solution the OP asked for then I will post it as such. If not, then the OP will surely clarify more specifically why such an easy solution doesn't solve the problem he/she is facing.